# Sum adjacent elements of a list if their values are equal using list comprehension in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am facing this problem where I need to add adjacent elements of a list if their value are equal in Python. Below are my list and expected outcome:

- `my_list = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]`
- `final_list = [3,0,2,0,2,0,1]`

Similarly, here is another example:

- `my_second_list = [1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]`
- `expected_outcome= [2,0,1,0,1]`

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and what's the problem you met?

Comment: Sorry man ..I don't have codes that i tried yesterday. I used for loops , few ways like if next value equal to current value , then sum values and append to an empty list, I got some results but not entirely.I tried more than 2 hours....slept over the problem thinking it will solve the issue.But did not get any lead .So asked here in the community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on an unsorted list:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [sum(group) for _, group in groupby(my_list)]
[3, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Wow....you solved the problem just like that...Thank you